# Из ссылки в текст через JS

Tags: javascript, html

Например есть текст такого рода : "На...поверхности...зуба кариозная полость средней глубины, выполненная светлым рыхлым дентином и т д..." и есть ссылки с номерами зубов такого вида

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="zubgetText(this)" id="18">18</a>
```

Можно ли сделать так  чтоб при нажатии на ссылку в вышеуказанном тексте вместо многоточий попадал номер зуба. Сейчас есть такой JS код ,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function zubgetText(el){
document.getElementById('lechenie').value += 
(document.getElementById('lechenie').value ? ', ' : '') + 
el.firstChild.data;
}
</script>
```

Видно что при таком раскладе при нажатии на ссылку заполняется инпут с айдишником lechenie.

Comment: Думаю нужно повесить этим многоточиям id и при клике заменять содержимое

Comment: ИНтересное решение а как можно повесить на них айди так как в одном тексте вместо многоточий иногда бывают и части и поверхности зуба

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот как можно это сделать.

```js
var lechenie_text = document.getElementById('lechenie').innerHTML;

function zubgetText(el){
    document.getElementById('lechenie').innerHTML = lechenie_text.replace(/\.\.\./gi, ' '+el.innerHTML+' ');
}
```

```html
<span id="lechenie">На...поверхности...зуба кариозная полость средней глубины, выполненная светлым рыхлым дентином.</span>
<br>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="zubgetText(this)" id="18">18</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="zubgetText(this)" id="10">10</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="zubgetText(this)" id="8">8</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="zubgetText(this)" id="4">4</a>
```

Регулярным выражением проходим по тексту и заменяем все вхождения в тексте, И для того что бы повторно использовать текст, мы сохраняем начальный текст в переменной `lechenie_text` .

Comment: Спасибо Вам за помощь, Razmik Galstyan, Вы очень помогли ! Но забыл сказать что текст , ну то что с многиточиями тоже находится в инпуте ) И он тоже заполняется из другой ссылки. Значит если захочу использовтаь инпут тоже можно пользоваться вышеуказанным кодом ?